# Simulating Geographic Routing in Wireless Sensor Networks Using Omnet++

Tags: routes, simulation, omnet++, mixim

I'm planning to simulate the geographic routing algorithm ( http://coitweb.uncc.edu/~ywang32/research/TPGF-shu.pdf )in wireless sensor networks using omnet++ and Mixim .

I need the following  details to proceed

- what should be the structure of a node?
- after specifying the details of the node, in which file should i write the actual code (routing )
- what all should i learn before doing this project?

Please direct me through the right path..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would consider going with INET 3.0 instead of MiXiM. Almost all features of MiXiM is now available in INET 3 (including MiXiM's more detailed physical models, the MAC protocols and some routing algorithms too). If you are interested in routing algorithms and don't care about the accuracy of the lower layers (physical transmission) the INET is definitely the way to go.

- take a look at the wireless tutorial and see which parts can be useful as a starting point: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/tutorials/wireless
- A geographic routing protocol as a starting point (GPSR). https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/src/inet/routing/gpsr